# Optimization of random variate algorithm for t-distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, algorithms, t-distribution, rejection-sampling

Consider the following polar [algorithm described by Bailey](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2153537):

1. Generate uniformly distributed variables $U, V$ in $(-1,1)$.
2. Let $W = U^2 + V^2$. If $W > 1$ go to step 1. Otherwise deliver $W$.

Now $C^2 = U^2/W$, and it is true, that:

- $W$ and $C^2$ are independent
- $W$ is uniformly distributed in $(0,1)$
- $C^2$ has the same density as $\cos^2(2\pi Z)$, where $Z$ is uniformly distributed in $(0,1)$.

Are these still true when as an optimization $V$ is generated in $(0,1)$ instead of $(-1,1)$?

If yes, then let $R^2 = \nu (W^{-2/\nu}-1)$, finally $X = \text{sign}(U)\sqrt{R^2C^2}$ is $t_\nu$ distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these still true when as an optimization $V$ is generated in
>   $(0,1)$ instead of $(-1,1)$?

Yes, because $V^2_{(0,1)}$ and $V^2_{(-1,1)}$ have the same distrubution.

Comment: Then $U$ could be also in $(0, 1)$, and $\text{sign}(U)$ can be changed to a random sign $S$.